# Interesting glitch-like behavior when testing SIGINT and SIGHUP on linux

Tags: c, linux

Lately have been testing out using signals such as SIGINT and SIGHUP and their role on ongoing processes on Linux. Running the following code returned some interesting results.

> ```
> #include <signal.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> void routine(int p){
>     puts("Not finishing");
>     sleep(2);
> }
>
> main(){
>     int i = 0;
>     signal(SIGINT, routine);
>     signal(SIGHUP, routine);
>
>     while(1){
>         printf("%d \n", i++);
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, it simply counts from 0 on an infinite loop. Then, by using kill -SIGINT on the process it created, I got the following:

[Routine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5nrS.png)

As you can see, before the line I requested the routine to print, the program repeated the last number (and it does not happen always). I would really like to know why.

Comment: You can't safely use stdio functions in signal handlers. See `man signal-safety` for the ones you can use.

Comment: Read this [To know why printf should not be used inside signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are narrowly avoiding horrible bugs by accident.

What I think is happening is that the signal sometimes interrupts while `printf` is in progress formatting the string into the output buffer. Then the `puts` in the signal handler inserts more string into the output buffer. Then the handler returns, `printf` inserts the newline and flushes the buffer.

But guess what would happen if this signal occurred just before the flush of a full 8K output buffer. The buffer positions would be at the end. Then the `puts` call happens, not realizing that `printf` is already in process of flushing and clearing the buffer. Where exactly would it be putting the `puts` string? At the beginning? At the end? Would the excess data `printf` was in the process of writing write over the string that `puts` had added? All of those things are possible.

Buffered C output is not reentrant and cannot be used in signal handlers.